# What solvent will dilute urethane glue?

Tags: woodworking

What is the ***solvent** that will **dilute*** the non-cyanoacrylate ***clear Gorilla Glue***?

Comment: To know what may dilute this glue, we would need to know what the ingredients are (if not cyanoacrylate), and then this might be more suited to chemistry.stackexchange.com

Comment: You're asking about _diluting_ glue, which would imply that you need it _thinner_ for some reason. Is that correct, or are you asking how to clean up hardened glue?

Answer (score 1):

Acetone or denatured alcohol will dilute and dissolve liquid urethane glue. However, they may not work on hardened glue. There are no practically-available solvents for that. You're left with mechanical removal of the crusty material.

[More on that](https://www.doityourself.com/stry/how-to-dissolve-polyurethane-glue#:%7E:text=Polyurethane%20Glue%20is%20a%20strong,acetone%20to%20dissolve%20polyurethane%20glue.)

Comment: I read somewhere else that you can wait for acetone to turn to soak into the glue, and then pull it out